# How to make compiler generate a "elf32-x86-64" format object file?

Tags: gcc, googletest, elf

### First, some background info about elf32-x86-64 format.

It is a format that leverages 64-bit hardware while enforcing 32-bit pointers. [Ref1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471056/gnu-linker-differences-between-the-different-32bit-emulation-modes) and [Ref2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).

### Question

I am trying to link the Google Test framework binaries to my project.

I use `objdump -f` to check the format of Google Test binaries and my binaries.

Google Test format is `elf64-x86-64`. Mine `elf32-x86-64`. So they cannot be linked together.

Then I add below content to the google test's internal_utils.cmake file:

```
set(ZEPHYR_LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--oformat=elf32-x86-64")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${ZEPHYR_LINK_FLAGS}")
```

I hope the **linker** flag can change the output format to `elf32-x86-64`.

But google test build failed with below error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

The `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so` is also a `elf64-x86-64` format.

And I checked the generated object file, such as:
 `./googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o`

It is **still** `elf64-x86-64`.

So it seems the linker flag doesn't affect the object file format.

I remember the linker `ld` will choose the output format based on its first encountered object file. So I guess I need to tell the **compiler** to output a `elf32-x86-64` format.

**How can I ask the compiler to output a `elf32-x86-64` object file?**

### ADD 1 - 3:29 PM 11/1/2019

I have managed to compile the Google Test as `elf32-x86-64` with below tuning:

- Add compile flag `-mx32`
- And add link flag `-Wl,--oformat=elf32-x86-64`

Now the output binaries `libgtest.a`, `libgtest_main.a` are `elf32-x86-64`. But they need to be linked to `libstdc++.so`. So far, it is `elf64-x86-64` on my system. And I haven't found a `elf32-x86-64` one. Thus below error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

### ADD 2 - 3:47 PM 11/1/2019

After installing `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74371/how-to-install-32-bit-version-of-libstdc-so-6-on-a-64-bit-machine)), I got a `elf32-x86-64` version of `libstdc++.so` at below location:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/x32/libstdc++.so
```

And it ultimately points to `/usr/libx32/libstdc++.so.6.0.25`

Now it seems I just need to find a way to tell the linker to use it... So close!

### ADD 3 - 2:44 PM 11/4/2019

Thanks to **Florian** and **EmployedRussian**, I change Google Test's `internal_utils.cmake` file to add below 4 lines:

```
set(MY_COMPILE_FLAGS "-mx32")
set(cxx_base_flags "${cxx_base_flags} ${MY_COMPILE_FLAGS}") 
set(MY_LINK_FLAGS "-mx32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${MY_LINK_FLAGS}")
```

Now the generated executable are `elf32_x86-64` format.

So basically, I add the `-mx32` to **both** compile and link flags.

And in the generated `rules.ninja` file, the link rule goes like this:

`command = $PRE_LINK && /usr/bin/c++  $FLAGS  $LINK_FLAGS $in  -o $TARGET_FILE $LINK_PATH $LINK_LIBRARIES && $POST_BUILD`

The `$FLAGS` and `$LINK_FLAGS` are defined in the `build.ninja` file as below:

```
FLAGS = -Wall -Wshadow -Werror  -mx32 ...
LINK_FLAGS = -mx32 ...
```

**So essentially, there are 2 `-mx32` options in the ninja command definition contributed by the `$FLAGS  $LINK_FLAGS` respectively.**

**So why do I need to specify the `-mx32` for twice??**

And I don't understand why I can specify `-mx32` for `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

First, `-mx32` is only a compile option ([ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mx32-2939)), **not** a linker option.

Second, from the link rule definition, the `$LINK_FLAGS` are passed to `usr/bin/c++` without a `-Wl,` prefix, so even the option can be appreciated by the linker, it won't be passed to the linker.

Comment: Have you seen this https://askubuntu.com/questions/85978/building-a-32-bit-app-in-64-bit-ubuntu? `export LDFLAGS='-m32 -L/usr/lib32'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GCC will adjust the linker command line accordingly if you invoke it as `gcc -mx32`. It is more than just a compiler flag.

Comment: To elaborate, adding link flag `-Wl,--oformat=elf32-x86-64`, is the *wrong* thing to do. Instead, add `-mx32` to the link line.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I tried adding `-Wl, -mx32` for the **linker**. My ultimate link flags  are `-Wl,-mx32  -rdynamic`. They are ultimately passed to `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-7` and then `/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd`. But I got this error: `/usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: x32`. It seems I shouldn't pass `-mx32` to the linker because it is recognized as the `-m` link option (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dm-emulation).

Comment: @FlorianWeimer If I only add the `-mx32` to the `g++` compile options, I got the `.o` file as `elf32_x86-64`, which is good. But the linker requires the **output** format to be `elf64_x86-64`. So I got this error `/usr/bin/ld: i386:x64-32 architecture of input file "googletest/CMakeFiles/sample2_unittest.dir/samples/sample2_unittest.cc.o" is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`. So it seems I have to **explicitly** tell the linker to output as `elf32_x86-64` format through the `-Wl,--oformat=elf32-x86-64`.

Comment: @smwikipedia You should pass `-mx32` *without* `-Wl,` prefix. You *must* use `-mx32` on *both* compile and link command lines.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks a lot! It seems to be working. Now I got the `elf32_x86-64` executable after putting `-mx32` for **both** compile and link flags. I will try more later. But I don't understand why I can pass the `-mx32` to link command line? It is a compiler option (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mx32-2939). But it is **NOT** listed as a `ld option`. And If I don't use the `-Wl,` prefix, it means it  will **NOT** be passed to the linker. Then why linker would care about it?

Comment: @smwikipedia Just because the `-mx32` isn't passed to the linker doesn't mean that is has no effect on the link line. In this case, presence of `-mx32` on the link line causes `gcc` to pass `-m elf32_x86_64` to `ld`. In addition, a different dynamic linker and different `crt0.o` are selected. Like the answer says: `-mx32` is *more* than just a compiler flag.

Comment: @EmployedRussian By `link line`, do you mean the `command line options` passed to the linker? IMHO, it will be much easier for me to understand if I only have to place the `-mx32` for once in the compile flag. And also I tried to place `-Wl, -melf32_x86_64` in the `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` becuase `-m` is a listed linker option. But it complains `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++`. So weird...

Comment: @EmployedRussian I updated my question with some analysis of the generated ninja build file. It seems to me a really weird usage paradigm...