# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 even when compiling with -m32 flags set?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, fuzzing

I am on a 64bit wsl2 machine, and I am trying to compile a 32bit program. To do so, I use these commands
CC="afl-clang" CXX="afl-clang++" ./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --host=i386 --build=i386 CFLAGS='-m32' CXXFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32'  and then I make clean all. Even still, when I run the program it says that the shared object it is trying to load is in the wrong ELFCLASS64. How do I fix this? The program is 32bit, but the shared objects that are also compiled are 64bit.

Comment: Since you're using --disable-shared, you should not be buidling any shared libraries.  Perhaps the build has dependencies on some external library that you only have installed as 64-bit and not 32-bit?  Which shared object is giving the error?

Comment: I put the wrong command. The shared object is a shared object made by the program. It is not an external object. It is made when u compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16004206/1216776

Comment: This results in an error saying c compiler cannot create executables

Comment: I could not fix the problem, but I just downloaded a new environment and made everything using 32bit.

I am guessing the solution is to use this command CC="afl-clang" CXX="afl-clang++" ./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no --host=i386 --build=i386 CFLAGS='-m32' CXXFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32', but also compile afl-clang with 32bit. afl-clang cannot create executables because it is a 64bit compiler.